# Distribution of function of gaussians

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $Z_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i,\Sigma_i)$, $i = 1,2$ be two Gaussian multivariate Random Variables.

Let $W = \max(Z_1,Z_2) - \min(Z_1,Z_2)$.

What is the distribution of $W$?

Comment: $W$ must be positive, so, not a Gaussian.

Comment: $W = \left|Z_1 - Z_2\right|$ is simply an absolute value of the gaussian r.v. $Z_1 - Z_2$.

Comment: Is it a convex function? Maybe quasi-convex?

Comment: what is $\max(Z_{1}, Z_{2})$ in multivariate case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comment you can rewrite:
$$
W = \max(Z_1,Z_2) - \min(Z_1,Z_2) = |Z_1−Z_2|. 
$$

$W$ is distributed as a Rectified Gaussian which has distribution

$$f(x;\mu ,\sigma ^{2})=\Phi (-{\frac  {\mu }{\sigma }})\delta (x)+{\frac  {1}{{\sqrt  {2\pi \sigma ^{2}}}}}\;e^{{-{\frac  {(x-\mu )^{2}}{2\sigma ^{2}}}}}{\textrm  {U}}(x), $$

and $U(x)$ is the unitary step function.

Comment: and $\Phi$ is ?